# core-js: "Attempting to configurable attribute of unconfigurable property."

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-polyfill

https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/279

I'm using babel-polyfill, which I believe uses core-js. I'm seeing this error reported in some browsers (Safari <=7, Chrome 47, Nintendo Browser, Playstation Vita Browser):
"Attempting to configurable attribute of unconfigurable property."
I used this site to translate the line & col number:
https://raygun.com/sourcemaps
It says the error is happening in core-js/modules/es6.math.acosh.js?7396

I removed the Math polyfills since I didn't need them, but I still see the error in core-js/modules/_object-to-array.js?7d99 on line 4.

What's causing this error and how do I make it go away?

Comment: Can you include the full error and stack trace?

Comment: No, it was reported through the `window.onerror` handler to Google Analytics. But I know it's happening inside this polyfill. I'll update my `window.onerror` to include the trace.

Comment: Turns out I was already including the trace, but it's just not available on the browsers this is a problem in.

Comment: Any solution for this?